# Flask - WSGI - No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, apache, web, flask, mod-wsgi

I've been following Sentdex' Flask tutorial. He's using a Venv to set up his Flask, but didn't set his Python up to work with a Venv. I've tried installing Flask globally - yet it still doesn't work. Trying to browse to the server returns a 500 Internal Server Error

I'm getting the usual `no module named flask`error.

**errorFGL.log**

```
[Sun Feb 05 11:22:32.043925 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26340:tid 118578538694400] [client 86.52.205.25:49814] mod_wsgi (pid=26340): Target WSGI script '/var/www-fgl/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Feb 05 11:22:32.044105 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26340:tid 118578538694400] [client 86.52.205.25:49814] mod_wsgi (pid=26340): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www-fgl/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Sun Feb 05 11:22:32.044243 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26340:tid 118578538694400] [client 86.52.205.25:49814] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Feb 05 11:22:32.045011 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26340:tid 118578538694400] [client 86.52.205.25:49814]   File "/var/www-fgl/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
[Sun Feb 05 11:22:32.045070 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26340:tid 118578538694400] [client 86.52.205.25:49814]     from FlaskApp import app as application
[Sun Feb 05 11:22:32.045549 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26340:tid 118578538694400] [client 86.52.205.25:49814]   File "/var/www-fgl/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Sun Feb 05 11:22:32.045594 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26340:tid 118578538694400] [client 86.52.205.25:49814]     from flask import Flask
[Sun Feb 05 11:22:32.045689 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26340:tid 118578538694400] [client 86.52.205.25:49814] ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "Success"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**flaskapp.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www-fgl/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = '[REDACTED]'
```

**fgl-database.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName [REDACTED]
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www-fgl/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www-fgl>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www-fgl/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
        <Directory /var/www-fgl/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorFGL.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/accessFGL.log combined




</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If you installed Flask globally, then mod_wsgi is likely compiled for a different Python version. For a Python virtual environment you need to tell mod_wsgi where it is. See: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As is polite behaviour when finding the solution, I googled around a bit more, and somehow managed to find a solution from a YouTube commment by Nathan Nichols here:

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps

1. Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf`
2. Add the following two lines before the "WSGIScriptAlias" line:

   ```
   WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-path=/var/www/FlaskApp:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
   ```
3. Restart Apache with "service apache2 restart"

I of course replaced the Python version with python3.5, which is what I'm running.

Comment: Don't use ``python-path`` to setup location of the Python virtual environment. Read the mod_wsgi docs on setting up Python virtual environment which I already supplied in comment to question. Use ``python-home`` instead. See: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Answer (score 23):

I wasted about 25 minutes finding a solution to this and after following all the other resources I could find, I also did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Make sure to have '-py3' at the end of libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 or the runtime will default to Python2.7

Source: https://vishnut.me/blog/ec2-flask-apache-setup.html

Comment: This was much easier than trying to get mod_wsgi to find a virtual env.

Answer (score 3):

First install python-virtualenv

Then from the Flask app directory where you put the wigs python files run

`virtualenv env`

This will create env directory inside the Flask directory and contains the local python installation.

Next activate the virtual environment by this command `source env/bin/activate`

After activating the virtual environment run `pip install flask`

Run `pip --version`

You will see something like this

pip 19.0.3 from /var/www/html/flaskapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Copy this python path

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-path=/var/www/html/flaskapp:/var/www/html/flaskapp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
```

Add above lines in FlaskApp.conf in sites-available directory of apache

Note put python-path what you get after running pip --version

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked for me, but I just add below line in starting of my .py and .wsgi file voila it worked:

```html
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/pythonVirtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages)
```

here `pythonVirtual` is my virtual directory for Python

Comment: Same here, hat to add site-packages of venv! Running on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core), Python 3.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

See the bottom of this page: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache

Where it says:

For Python 3 add the following lines to the top of your .wsgi file:

```
activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Where /path/to/env is the path to any virtual environment where you installed Flask, as described by others here on this thread.  The "python-path" and some of the other VirtualHost configurations described here are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html.
2. You should edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf`
3. Add these above the `WSGIScriptAlias`

   `WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-home=/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/FlaskApp`
   `WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp`

I met the same problem and fix it by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
create a python virtualenv and install torch in it:

```
source /home/user/virtual_environments/torch/bin/activate
pip install flask
```

step 2: add this to flaskapp.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/flaskapp.conf

```
cat sites-enabled/flaskapp.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin youemail@email.com

        WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
        WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-home=/home/user/virtual_environments/torch

               WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
               <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                       Order allow,deny
                       Allow from all
               </Directory>
               Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
               <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                       Order allow,deny
                       Allow from all
               </Directory>
               ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
               LogLevel warn
               CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```